# Is it possible to save MySQL Workbench files as plain XML?

Tags: mysql, xml, mysql-workbench

DB Designer had a lot of bugs but one outstanding feature was that **database models were saved in plain XML by default**.

This allowed a user to **diff file versions via SVN or Beyond Compare**, easily finding any changes made to the database.

Unfortunately, DB Designer's succsssor, MySQL Workbench, stores files in a **proprietary MVW file format**, which is unreadable.

**Is it possible to force MySQL Workbench to save as XML?**

Comment: For future readers of this post: I know this question is very old, but [I have posted a workaround that seems to work well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33614759/2057919). I use it with Mercurial, but there is no reason the basic concept would not work with SVN.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the current version (5.2.10 beta) does not support that.

However, the file format is not proprietary - its a simple zip archive. It contains a single XML document which is the complete database model. I wrote [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361059/subversion-diff-for-zipped-xml-file) a couple of months ago with the same goal as you seem to have. I wanted to be able to do `svn diff model.mwb`

The answer I got there helped me write a small script which unzipped the file before passing it to the diff tool. It worked decently and if you're interested I can post it somewhere.

I also very recently started a [thread on the Workbench forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?153,295656,295656#msg-295656) about this issue. Hopefully someone on the development team can provide some more input on this.

EDIT: it is now being tracked by [MySQL Bug #51203](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=51203) with a target of 6.0.

Comment: If it is being zipped purely to keep file sizes down, it shouldn't be too hard to add this as a configurable setting?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint Oskar. I didn't know that the workbench file is a simple zip with xml files

Comment: For future readers of this post: I know this question is very old, but [I have posted a workaround that seems to work well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33614759/2057919). I use it with Mercurial, but there is no reason the basic concept would not work with SVN.