# How can I require that two files be included in the same subversion commit?

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook

I develop projects with databases which are maintained as a MySQL workbench file, which is a binary file.  Since you can't easily tell the difference in a binary file between to commits, it's required that you update the SQL create script for that schema before committing.  That way, you can run a diff of the SQL file to see what changed.

Sometimes, people either forget or get lazy and don't update the SQL file.  How can I use subversion to require that any commit which includes the workbench file must also include the SQL file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a Hook Script on the server to make this a requirement.

You can use the pre-commit-hook to check if it contains the workbench file and check if it contains the SQL file as well...if not abort the commit.

Comment: Definitely a great solution.. just want to make sure I don't overlook an obvious alternative to making custom modifications to the hook scripts first.

Answer (score 1):

Although khmarbaise's answer is working, I propose you a better solution. Instead of forcing developers to edit the SQL file, try to update it automatically. It means that in a step of your build process (suppose that you have a build process) check the Workbench file and in the case of its update, change your SQL file automatically.

Comment: Sounds like a great solution, but I'm not sure whether MySQL Workbench has a way to script the creation of an SQL file.  I'll have to look into it.

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL Workbench doesn't have a robust command line interface and doesn't appear to be able to accomplish this with any sort of ease at this time.

Comment: If that is not possible, try to create the DB by the workbench file and generate the SQL script. As a rule, do not place two items on your source control that represent the same concept. It you have no way, you SHOULD update one automatically when the other is changing. Do NOT trust your developers to keep them updated.

Comment: Agreed on principle, but in practice it is not possible to follow this rule in this scenario under the current circumstances.  Unless someone proposes a better solution which can be practically implemented, requiring a commit of two files is the next best thing.  (Jealous of your location btw, it's a place I'd like to visit someday)

Comment: Ok then Brad. But remember that having both files in a commit does not guarantee the integrity of the files, coz the script may have be changed wrongly !!! (That's too kind of you. Count on me if you intended to visit someday :) )

Answer (score 0):

Unlike your question, I found that workbench files are not binary files. They are zipped files that contain the schema of the db in an xml format. See these two posts: [Is it possible to save MySQL Workbench files as plain XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827855/is-it-possible-to-save-mysql-workbench-files-as-plain-xml)   and   [Subversion diff for zipped xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361059/subversion-diff-for-zipped-xml-file)

Comment: That's true.  I said binary because a zip is a binary file.  If you go in to read the XML the zip contains you find it's quite the perversion.  Plus many tags have a _ptr_ attribute that changes on every save, rendering any basic diff useless, short of filtering out those lines.  Even if you did, it's still a low quality way of viewing what changed.