# hg diff on MySQL Workbench files

Tags: xml, mercurial, diff, mysql-workbench, hgignore

*I'm [posting this as a Q&A](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to document a workaround for a problem that seems to come up frequently—how to put MySQL Workbench files under version control—but for which I have been unable to find any solutions. Feedback is welcome!*

How can I tell Mercurial to `diff` the contents of a zipped archive and ignore some of the changes to those contents? Specifically, how can I use `hg` to diff the contents of a MySQL Workbench (`.mwb`) file, ignoring the many unimportant changes that MySQL Workbench makes every time the file is opened? Can I use a custom script that ignores certain irrelevant changes?

## Background

I am trying to `diff` a file in an hg repository. The file, `document.mwb.xml`, is an XML document extracted from a `.mwb` file (a MySQL Workbench model file). Basically, I am looking to keep the model's contents—the table structure, visual model, etc.—under version control, but not commit the `.mwb` file itself, which is a zip archive and thus a binary file.

Anytime I save the `.mwb` file, I unzip it. I keep the unzipped contents in my repository, and just zip them up again when I need to work with the `.mwb` in MySQL.

The XML in question looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data grt_format="2.0" document_type="MySQL Workbench Model" version="1.4.4">
  <value type="object" struct-name="workbench.Document" id="8551CCFA-3AD0-4207-BC76-15ED589CF22C" struct-checksum="0x7131bf99">
    <value type="object" struct-name="workbench.logical.Model" id="B48E1CD2-3386-40B7-8E59-AA191598F667" struct-checksum="0xf4220370" key="logicalModel">
      <value _ptr_="0x7fbcd1cc3270" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="workbench.logical.Diagram" key="diagrams"/>
      <value _ptr_="0x7fbcd1cc3210" type="dict" key="customData"/>
      <value _ptr_="0x7fbcd1cc32d0" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="model.Marker" key="markers"/>
      <value _ptr_="0x7fbcd1cc3330" type="dict" key="options"/>
      <value type="string" key="name"></value>
      <link type="object" struct-name="GrtObject" key="owner">8551CCFA-3AD0-4207-BC76-15ED589CF22C</link>
    </value>
    <value _ptr_="0x7fbcd1cc2b70" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="workbench.OverviewPanel" key="overviewPanels"/>
    <value _ptr_="0x7fbcd1cc2c00" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="workbench.physical.Model" key="physicalModels">
      <value type="object" struct-name="workbench.physical.Model" id="34B9E967-5C9B-4D1B-8759-C417F6C33AA3" struct-checksum="0x5f896d18">
...
```

The problem is all of those `_ptr_` attributes: there are literally thousands of them in this file, and every one of them changes every single time the file is saved, even if nothing is modified. As a result, the repository can rapidly get cluttered with completely meaningless "changes" to this file.

Is there a way to use a custom `diff` routine to ignore these irrelevant changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not found a true solution, but I have developed a satisfactory workaround, inspired by this [mwb-diff gist](https://gist.github.com/rubenvincenten/085ffde61e8c9f880665). This allows me to unzip and diff the `.mwb` file's contents, commit those contents and their changes to the repository, and use the `.mwb` normally when necessary.

## Project Structure

My project is set up like this:

```
project_root
    /dist
    /schema
    /src
    /test
```

I save the `.mwb` file - call it `MyModel.mwb` - in `project_root/schema`. Obviously, you can use a different structure, but you will need to modify the instructions below accordingly.

## The Scripts

I created the following scripts and saved them in `project_root/schema`:

**unpack.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Unzip the model (MyModel.mwb) into a particular directory (project_root/schema/MyModel)
unzip -o MyModel.mwb -d MyModel/

# Replace all _ptr_="...." attributes with _ptr_="xxx"
sed -i presed -E 's/_ptr_="0x[0-9a-f]+"/_ptr_="xxx"/g' MyModel/document.mwb.xml
```

**pack.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# This file goes into the directory containing the model contents, zips them up, and saves them as a .mwb model

cd MyModel/
zip -r ../MyModel.mwb ./* -x lock
cd ..
```

## Getting Mercurial Ready to Rock

We need to tell `hg` to ignore the model (and all other `.mwb` files). Also, when MySQL Workbench is open, it adds a `lock` file to the `.mwb` archive, which we need to ignore. So, add these lines to your `.hgignore` file:

```
*.mwb
*.mwb.bak
schema/MyModel/lock
```

> ### An Aside About the `data.db` File
>
> Optionally, also ignore the `data.db` file (a SQLite database) in the
>   `.mwb` file. It is a binary file that contains any `INSERT`s or other
>   non-create SQL statements that are part of your model. As a rule, I
>   don't use MySQL Workbench for this stuff; I use it only to create and
>   edit tables, views, etc. So, I added this line to `.hgignore`:
>
> ```
> schema/MyModel/data.db
> ```
>
> If you want to track changes to the `data.db` file, you may need to
>   modify this workaround.

## How to Use the Scripts

When you want to modify the `.mwb` file, rebuild it from its components by running `pack.sh` above. This could be added as a [hook](https://selenic.com/hg/help/hgrc) to happen automatically when you `hg pull`, update, etc., but I haven't explored this, yet.

When you are done editing the `.mwb` file and want to commit your changes, run the `unpack.sh` script. If you want, you can set up a file-watching utility on your system to do this automatically when the file changes, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

## The Results

Mercurial is now perfectly happy to track changes to the contents of your `.mwb` file without tracking thousands of apparently-useless `_ptr_` attributes. Also, while I am using this with Mercurial, the basic logic (and the shell scripts) will work with git, SVN, etc.

**IMPORTANT CAVEAT:** As far as I can tell, the `_ptr_` attributes are irrelevant. The scripts I have posted above actually replace the contents of those attributes. `_ptr_="0x98a7b3e4"` (or whatever) becomes `_ptr_"xxx"`. Based on my testing, this doesn't matter, and MySQL Workbench will happily work with the reconstituted file, apparently disregarding the `_ptr_` values. *I may be wrong, and these values may matter!* You are strongly encouraged to test this for yourself before relying on my solution.